# Is it possible to create IOS 16 Lock Screen Widgets with Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, widget

I was wondering if Flutter has access to that yet, if not, can I edit the IOS Folder to add the Lock Screen Widgets to my app?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Lock Screen Widget for Flutter. You need to make it in SwiftUI on iOS(Xcode) natively.